# executing functions in OCaml from fileinput of OCaml

Tags: ocaml

How to execute (in OCaml) the lines we get from fileinput described below?

```
let read_file filename =   
  let lines = ref [] in  
    let chan = open_in filename in  
    try   
      while true; do   
        lines := input_line chan :: !lines   
      done; []   
    with End_of_file ->  
      close_in chan;   
      List.rev !lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear (to me) what you're asking. If you have a file containing some OCaml code, one way to run it is to load it into the toplevel. First, create a file named fileread.ml containing your text. Then (from the command line):

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# #use "fileread.ml";;
val read_file : string -> string list = <fun>
# read_file "fileread.ml";;
- : string list =
["let read_file filename ="; "let lines = ref [] in";
 "let chan = open_in filename in"; "try"; "while true; do";
 "lines := input_line chan :: !lines"; "done; []"; "with End_of_file ->";
 "close_in chan;"; "List.rev !lines"]
```

If, instead, you're asking how an OCaml program can load text and execute it as OCaml code, this isn't something OCaml can do directly. Naturally there are ways to do it; the toplevel is after all an OCaml program. But there's no simple function in OCaml for executing text, as there is in many interpreted languages (often being named `eval`).

If, on the third hand, you're asking how to compile and run your code, add a line like this to the end of fileread.ml:

```
let () = List.iter print_endline (read_file "fileread.ml")
```

Then compile and run as follows:

```
$ ocamlc -o fileread fileread.ml
$ fileread
let read_file filename =
let lines = ref [] in
let chan = open_in filename in
try
while true; do
lines := input_line chan :: !lines
done; []
with End_of_file ->
close_in chan;
List.rev !lines

let () = List.iter print_endline (read_file "fileread.ml")
```